# Rails Carrierwave: How do I reduce Attachment size from 7-15Mb to 7Mb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, carrierwave

my `Post` model:
`mount_uploaders :attachments, AttachmentUploader`

I have current goals:

- If the attachment is Photo and the file size is from 7 to 15mb Carrierwave should reduce the size to mb.
- If the attachment is Photo and the file size is more than 10mb I should throw an error.
- If attachment is Video and file size is more than 200mb I should throw an error.

Tried to do this in `News` model:

```
validate :file_size

  def file_size
    attachments.each do |attachment|
       extn = attachment.content_type
       size = attachment.size
       if ["image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"].include?(extn) && size > 7.megabytes.to_f
         errors.add(:attachment, "Max Photo size is 7MB")
        elsif ["application/mp4", "application/mov"].include?(extn) && size > 200.megabytes.to_f
         errors.add(:attachment, "Max video size is 200MB")
       end
    end
end
```

Which only validates the size, but doesn't reduce the size it if it exceeds 7mb.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only throws an error message if the size is > 7mb. 
You might want to convert the file to png, or reduce quality of the image. These are given features by the gem. There is no such method to limit the max size to 7mb after conversion. 
You might want to validate the file_size and if it exceeds 7mb you might want to have a method to reduce the file_size.